# How to display a list on a toggledropdown nav divided by 5?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have data from my database that was needed to append on my navbar dropdown.

This is my json data:

```
{
    "1": [{
        "id": 1,
        "moduleId": "1",
        "dropdownModuleName": "NL",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 17:37:21",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "moduleId": "1",
        "dropdownModuleName": "EE",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:01:39",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "moduleId": "1",
        "dropdownModuleName": "SA",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": "1",
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:01:46",
        "dateUpdated": "2018-09-19 18:10:02"
    }],
    "4": [{
        "id": 4,
        "moduleId": "4",
        "dropdownModuleName": "CON",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "updatedBy": "1",
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 18:01:56",
        "dateUpdated": "2018-09-19 18:13:33"
    },{
        "id": 6,
        "moduleId": "4",
        "dropdownModuleName": "RG",
        "isDeleted": null,
        "createdBy": "1",
        "updatedBy": null,
        "dateCreated": "2018-09-19 19:13:00",
        "dateUpdated": null
    }],
}
```

using this script I was able to display the data on my navbar dropdown, but the problem was when the data is too long some of the links on my navdropdown can't be seen on my screen.

I have tried using `chunkarray` to divide the array but since I need to get the data from my array I need to convert the array to JSON and so the result was it becomes a list instead of dividing it.

```
    $.ajax({
       url:'/api/navbarToggleDropdownMenu/getall',
       type:'GET',
       dataType:'JSON',
       async:false,
       success:function (res) {

           for(i in res){
              myKey = i;
              myVal = res[i]
                 for(o in myVal){
                    nKey = o 
                    nVal = myVal[o]
                    if(nVal.moduleId != undefined || nVal.moduleId != null){
                        $('[data-id="'+myKey+'"]').replaceWith('<li  class="dropdown megamenu-fw"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">'+nVal.moduleName+'</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu-content" role="menu"><li [data-div="'+myKey+'"]></li></ul></li>');

                        $('[data-div="'+myKey+'"]').append('<div class="col-menu col-md-3"><ul class="menu-col">
<li><a href="dropdownModule?id='+nVal.id+'">'+nVal.dropdownModuleName+'</a></li></ul></div>');

                      }
                 }
            }

       }
    })
```

what I want  it to do is to display the data on my navbar by dividing the list so if the list is greater than 5 it will create another `div class="col-md-3"` and display the continuation of the list saying my list has 10 first 5 goes to the first `col-md-3` then the next will be on the other `col-md-3`.

so this it what i want to be displayed

```
<li class="dropdown megamenu-fw">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">Megamenu</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu-content" role="menu">
    <li>                               
      </div><!-- end col-3 -->  
        <div class="col-menu col-md-3">
          <ul class="menu-col">
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="shortcodes.html">Shortcodes</a></li>
            <li><a href="authors.html">Author</a></li>
            <li><a href="404.html">404</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-me.html">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- end col-3 -->
        <div class="col-menu col-md-3">
          <ul class="menu-col">
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="shortcodes.html">Shortcodes</a></li>
            <li><a href="authors.html">Author</a></li>
            <li><a href="404.html">404</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-me.html">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- end col-3 -->
      </div><!-- end row -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you share your required html here.

Comment: i updated my question with the result html..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should linearize your data as an array then with a simple counter append the open and end tag when needed

```js
const exampleData = Array(28)
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, i) => `LI ${i + 1}`);

const ulSize = 5;

const openTag =
  `<div class="col-menu col-md-3">
    <ul class="menu-col">`;

const closeTag =
  ` </ul>
   </div>`;

let liCounter = 0; 
$('code').html(exampleData.reduce((c, n, i, arr) => {
  if (liCounter === 0) c.push(openTag);
  c.push(`<li><a href="#">${n}</a></li>`);
  liCounter++;
  if (liCounter === ulSize || i === arr.length - 1) {
    c.push(closeTag);
    liCounter = 0;
  }
  return c;
}, []).join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code></code>
```

Comment: Thanks this works.. but can you help me i still have a problem regarding this..
cause i want to display the list of data based on their moduleId..

Comment: You mean ordered by moduleId?